# When two CCMenuItem overlaps each other, is it possible to prioritise one over the other?

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 CCMenuItems A and B

A is a screen-wide transparent button
and B is an actual button that is set to visible when A is touched

Currently, when I'm touching B, A responds with it's selector method and basically B does not respond because the touch is 'taken' by A's selector.

I need B to be responding even though A is a screen-wide button so- Is it possible to prioritise B's selector when it is pushed?

To summarize, I'm toggling B's visibility via A and would like to be able to use B when it is visible.

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

for me worked adding one menu in one layer and another menu in other layer

Comment: It would be better if you elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I)**

Yes, You can prioritize your `CCMenuItems` by setting Z-Order.

**First button that gets touch is the button with lowest Z-Order.**

**II)**

And if you want to prioritize your `CCMenu`s, you need to `setTouchPriority(..)` them.

**The less priority you give, the earlier your `CCMenu` will handle the touch. (`CCMenu`'s default value is -128 ).**

Answer (score 0):

Either you can set the buttons yourButton.isEnabled to NO or you can just move the A-button off the scene when you don't want it to take input.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the problem with this approach is I will lose the function of button A. I'm hoping to be able to toggle the B button whenever I touch anywhere on the screen, even when B is visible.

Comment: Ah ok, what if you change their z using reorderChild? Could that help? It's easier if I can see some code.

Comment: Thanks for your help Zebulon. I'm not sure how do I use reorderChild. I've tried setting the z on init the larger button z=1 and the smaller buttons that is supposed to be appearing above it to be z=2. It seems to have an effect on the image's z order(i've changed the transparent layer into a translucent one) but doesn't really help the selector priority.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use an additional CCMenu with a higher z-order for the button B.